# How to improve performance for rendering dashboard built using react.js

Tags: reactjs, performance, dashboard

building dashboard using react. The dashboard has 4 charts. same data to be sent to each chart. the dashboard has filter options, It takes too much time to render the charts in the dashboard. Evertime , i use filter, again it takes too much time to re-render the charts in the dashboard. how to improve the performance of dashboard.

have used memo, callback etc. How this dashboard with various charts should be handled. what is the best/correct way to send the same data to all the four charts to render it quickly.

Answer (score 0):

---

In your case, I think applying filters at the frontend.
Applying filters at the frontend is often faster and provides a more responsive user experience
and controls the rendering process using the debouncing technique.

```
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
const [debouncedValue, setDebouncedValue] = useState(inputValue);
useEffect(() => {
  const handler = setTimeout(() => {
    setDebouncedValue(inputValue);
  }, 1000);
  return () => {
    clearTimeout(handler);
  };
}, [inputValue]);
```